# Can a slide be copied into PowerPoint 2010 without copying across it's corresponding slide layout too?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010, slideshow

I've got a problem here - I'm trying to copy existing slides from a PowerPoint 2003 presentation into a new PowerPoint 2010 presentation. It copies across fine, but it also dumps the slide layout from the PP2003 file into the master of the PP2010 file - which i'm trying to avoid. The old slide layouts are not valid with our corporate standard any more and shouldn't be in the new file.

Is there a way to copy across the old slide WITHOUT bringing its slide layout across into PP2010 too? I have been told that you could do this between MS Office 2003 presentations by copying to and from the Slide Sorter view - but this doesn't seem to work in PP2010.

Using 'Use Destination Theme' still copies across the old slide's layout into the new set of layouts and this is what I am trying to avoid.

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Tom

Comment: So you are trying to retrieve plain text from the old slides without any formatting ? One more thing, next time if you have any query about an answer, post is as a **comment** not as a **answer**.

Comment: Apologies, I was on a mobile device and the interface isn't quite as obvious as it could be. And yes - basically I'm just trying to copy across the slide and nothing else - and then apply a new layout to it. I don't see how I can do this without copying text objects straight across - but this copies them in as 'dumb' text items and doesn't apply the new formatting rules.

Comment: By that, I mean just copying the old text objects from the initial file straight across into the new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of anybody who happens across this - there are workarounds that are discussed in the following link. Primarily, by disabling 'preserve master' in the source file and then copying it into the new file by choosing 'keep source formatting' - when a new layout is then applied, the old one disappears when its no longer in use as the source master is unpreserved.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/can-a-slide-be-copied-into-powerpoint-2010-without/27aa7b42-cad9-4e59-a4e6-080796c628fc

Answer (score 1):

Open both PPT files in Office 2010, copy the slide you want from the old ppt and in newer version, 
**Right Click** and you will see 3 types of **paste options** available.
One of them is called `Use Destination theme` select this one and it will paste that slide with the new theme.

[image]

[See more details here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/copy-and-paste-your-slides-HA010338347.aspx).

Comment: That's fine - and that works - but if you then go into view + slide master you will see that it has also copied across the slide's text layout, so its not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

With all information I could find, I have ascertained that any slide that is copied in using Keep Source Formatting will automatically be given the "Title and Content" Layout by the new presentation. It doesn't bring along the old layout - rather it just creates one to use when copying in the old slide, and you have to manually change that by choosing Layout > *Pick layout*

This is annoying for me because the "Title and Content" layout that it uses temporarily is not approved by our corporate standard. Which means that unless the user manually removes it from the Slide Master view after applying the new layout, it will never be removed - and in fact will be an OPTION when choosing the 'New Slide' dropdown.

I have had to dedicate time to writing a VBA script that detects any layouts that are not corporately approved to run on save, so that they are removed.

Thanks
Tom